# Maximum Revenue

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A small theater has a seating capacity of 2000. When the ticket price is $20, attendance is 1500. For each 1 dollar decrease in price, attendance increases by 100. (a) Write the revenue R of the theater as a function of ticket price x. (b) What ticket price will yield a maximum revenue? what is the maximum revenue?

Comment: Just asking - but when the price increases, shouldn't the attendance decrease? (Not a correction to the problem...)

Comment: Yes it should but I didn't create the problem. I just get stuck trying to solve it :)

Comment: The question says "when the price DECREASES by $1 the attendance increases."

Answer (score 1):

Hint: how many people come if tickets are $19?$ Now can write an expression for the number who come at price $x$? The revenue is this times $x$

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

For every dollar decrease in price, there is an increase in attendence of 100.  This can be represented by a derivative function

$$\frac{dP}{dA} = \frac{-1}{100}$$

Integrating $$P = \frac{-1}{100}A + C$$

When P = 20, A = 1500, giving you the constant C = 35

Thus $$A = (35-P).100$$

$$Revenue = P.A$$

Substituting A in the above equation, you get

$$Revenue = P.(100).(35-P)$$

Maximum Revenue happens when $$\frac{dR}{dP} = 0$$

Thus giving you $$200P = 3500$$

Giving you the price = $$ $17.5 $$

Maximum Revenue = $$(17.5).(100).(35-17.5)$$  $$=$30625$$

Comment: Why a downvote?  Is it because I gave away the answer?